# How to hold 3 different values ​in a node in the avl tree

Tags: c, tree, avl-tree

ı want to hold 2 different types value (char,char,int) in the same node in the avl tree. but I couldn't make the connection between them. char values are name and lesson, int value is number.

ıs there any example for this subject? ı couldnt find any example.

Comment: Do you have any code written?

Comment: yes but ıt's too long. and standart avl tree. should ı share

Comment: I just don't understand your question. Do you have a node struct? You can just add members.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/ ı used thıs code (c code) and using struct node.

Comment: You can just add to `Node`. `char a; char b; int i;`

Comment: okey ı added. how can connect char with int values. because ı sorted by char value(person name) and ı need this person's number how can ı make

Comment: What do you mean connect?

Comment: ıt ıs a homework and ı sorted by name but how can i add this person's number. how can i connect name and number this 2 values.

Comment: So you search through the tree for a person then set the number member. I'm still not sure I understand the question.

Comment: my bad english sorry ı wıll  try again.

Comment: There is one avl tree. indexing data by name in this tree. but I need to keep both the name and number on a node. I don't know how to add the number to this node.

Comment: You have single letter name and lesson entries? Consider double-checking that you do not need arrays of characters to store more than one letter for those things.

Comment: Otherwise it seems that what you are looking for is the concept of `struct`s.